# How to login only once when you're looping through a CSV file in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm a beginner in Selenium, and my trying to build an automation that loops through different URLS in a csv file, and does several actions on page.

It's almost working, but I just can't figure how to make the selenium bot login only for the first URL.

Here's my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv
from itertools import islice

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')

with open('C:/Users/Monica/projects/myfile.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in islice(csv_reader,1,None):
        driver.get(row[0])
        
        login_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='login-trigger']")
        login_btn.click()
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        email_input = driver.find_element_by_id("login_email")
        email_input.send_keys("myemail@gmail.com")
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        password_input = driver.find_element_by_id("login_password")
        password_input.send_keys("XXXXXXXXXX")
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        connect_btn = driver.find_element_by_id("login_submit")
        connect_btn.click()
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "// [@id='content']/div[1]/div/ul[1]/li/a/span")))
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
        sendmessage_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[1]/div/ul[1]/li/a/span")
        sendmessage_btn.click()
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
        textbox_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='message_text']")
        textbox_input.send_keys("Hey ")
        textbox_input.send_keys(row[1])
   
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
        finalmessage_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='message_submit']/span")
        finalmessage_btn.click()
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 120)
        
driver.close()
```

Indeed, the login part of the flow is only needed for the first URL (login_btn, email_input & password_input), and then, for the rest of the URLs in the CSV file, I just need to click on a button and send messages (after the connect_btn button to the end of the flow).

Because my current flow doesn't take this into account, I get the following error message when trying to open the 2nd URL of the file.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='login-trigger']
```

How can I modify my code to login only once ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could seperate out the login procedure with that first url and then open up the CSV file with the rest of them. That is if you only need to login once. That is make sure within your CSV file that you don't have the first url.

Again not knowing what is within your CSV file/The URL you're using selenium for limits me some what to make further suggestions.

### Code Example

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv
from itertools import islice

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
first_url = 'XXX' 
driver.get(first_url)
        
login_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='login-trigger']")
login_btn.click()
        
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
email_input = driver.find_element_by_id("login_email")
email_input.send_keys("myemail@gmail.com")
        
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
password_input = driver.find_element_by_id("login_password")
password_input.send_keys("XXXXXXXXXX")
        
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
connect_btn = driver.find_element_by_id("login_submit")
connect_btn.click()
        

with open('C:/Users/Monica/projects/myfile.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in islice(csv_reader,1,None):
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "// [@id='content']/div[1]/div/ul[1]/li/a/span")))
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
        sendmessage_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[1]/div/ul[1]/li/a/span")
        sendmessage_btn.click()
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
        textbox_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='message_text']")
        textbox_input.send_keys("Hey ")
        textbox_input.send_keys(row[1])
   
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
        finalmessage_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='message_submit']/span")
        finalmessage_btn.click()
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 120)
        
driver.close()
```

### Alternative

The other alternative is that you could use a try and except block on the login parts of your code.
You'll need to import `from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException`

Add this under your `driver.get[0]`

```
try: 
    login_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='login-trigger']")
    login_btn.click()
    
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    email_input = driver.find_element_by_id("login_email")
    email_input.send_keys("myemail@gmail.com")
    
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
    password_input = driver.find_element_by_id("login_password")
    password_input.send_keys("XXXXXXXXXX")
    
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    connect_btn = driver.find_element_by_id("login_submit")
    connect_btn.click()
    
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "// [@id='content']/div[1]/div/ul[1]/li/a/span")))
    
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    sendmessage_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[1]/div/ul[1]/li/a/span")
    sendmessage_btn.click()
except NoSuchElementsException: 
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "// [@id='content']/div[1]/div/ul[1]/li/a/span")))

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    sendmessage_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[1]/div/ul[1]/li/a/span")
    sendmessage_btn.click()

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    textbox_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='message_text']")
    textbox_input.send_keys("Hey ")
    textbox_input.send_keys(row[1])


    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    finalmessage_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='message_submit']/span")
    finalmessage_btn.click()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 120)
```

### Tips

1. You may want to consider putting the login procedure and opening the CSV file into seperate functions. Particularly if you are going to have extra code.

### Update Based on comments

So based on comments sounds like you need abit more help on logging in firstly and then seperating out the URLs with the CSV. Here is the login procedure which is pretty easy to follow. It's within a function to seperate out different parts of the program which is what we should be doing.

```
from selenium import webdriver


def login(driver):
    driver.get('https://erasmusu.com/en/login/do#login_popup')
    driver.find_element_by_id('login_email').send_keys('xxxxx')
    driver.find_element_by_id('login_password').send_keys('xxxxx')
    driver.find_element_by_id('login_submit').click()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'c:\users\aaron\chromedriver.exe')
    login(driver)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this detailed answer ! Sadly, both methods are not working. For example, for the 1rst one, it does login, but it doesn't open the URLs in the csv file. The website is login protected, but here is a [screenshot] (https://imgur.com/O7mjWAgof) of the page I'm redirected to and the error I get `element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='content']/div[1]/div/ul[1]/li/a/span")))`

Comment: The imgur link isnt working! That's strange that it does't open the URLs, have you tried a couple of print statements to see that it's grabbing the links from your CSV file ? as long as the webdriver hasn't closed and you're logged in, it should be able use the links. Have you tried the try and except block too ?

Comment: That's weird... here's a link that should works [screenshot] (https://imgur.com/O7mjWAg). And yes,  when I use print statements, the program prints the URLS... As for the try and except block, I have also tried it, but I get the following error `element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "// [@id='content']/div[1]/div/ul[1]/li/a/span")))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\virtual_workspace\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message`

Comment: What's happening with the browser activity ? As in when you run the program, viewing the chromedriver as it pops up. Is the browser activity behaving how it should ? Sometimes selenium is a bit funny. Essentially you want to see the browser log on. Then see the browser go to the urls within the CSV. I'm, presuming the urls within the CSV are on the same site you're logging in ?

Comment: Yes, that's right ! Well, when I use Selenium, for some reason, I am redirected to the home page (https://imgur.com/O7mjWAg), whereas when Iconnect to a profile page manually, I am correctly redirected to the profile page... (https://imgur.com/uvI4LE7).

Comment: In your original code, you're making several logins based on each url. My code was an attempt to login only once, then make webdriver go to the URLs in your csv file. 
So when you run the code, are you successfully logging in ? It may be redirecting to the home page after login, which is fine, because you can use driver.get() with the urls in the csv, it should just load that page up with the same session and remember you're logged in.

Comment: The key here is you want to seperate the login component of your program from the opening the CSV files. It's better to put these in seperate functions really. Even starting from the very beginning, getting the code to just log you in successfully. Before thinking about the CSV file.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a simple login procedure encapsulated with a function. That should start you off. Can you confirm that logs you in ? Because thats the first part of the program. Then it's just a case of making a function with a for loop and opening the CSV file and making sure it's getting onto the pages in the CSV file.

Comment: Yes, I successfully login when I run the code with the previous versions of the code and the updated answer you provided, thanks ! Yes, indeed I was a little bit confused as how to write functions, I was just looking it up. So if I understand correctly, I need to create a new function for the rest of program using the same structure you used for the login part ?

Comment: It's not that its needed. Functions make code easier to read and forms the basis for a paradigm of coding called functional programming. My suggestion would be create a function that takes the driver as an argument like I did for the login function and make it do one thing. That one thing to me means opening up the CSV file, and directing the webdriver to the urls in that CSV. Start off small, try one URL to make sure it's kept you logged in and you're able to get to one of the URLs in the csv file.

Comment: You might want to check it something like this. https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/ if you've never coded with functions.

Comment: That's super helpful, thanks ! I'm going to try and rewrite my code using functions.

Comment: Let me know how you get on, post your code if you're struggling.